# Nodemon crashing on start with no trace when using 'agenda'

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

> RESOLVED:

Changes in the answer below needed to happen for this to get resolved although as a note there's another issue if using nodemon / grunt-nodemon where 1.2.x silences console output for some reason so if testing with console it won't work. 1.3.x has the fix, Update and resolve any dependency issues. I ended up moving the fixed code below to under my app = express() line. And placed any agenda-ui lines with the rest of my app.use() middleware.

Also if using agenda-ui some breaking have been introduced that return a "cannot read property of undefined" when trying to hit the /agenda-ui endpoint. Not sure why yet but there is an open bug report.

> ORIGINAL POST

I KNOW that I'm the problem here. I have built an app and want to use 'agenda' for backend job scheduling. App works fine without agenda lines in server.js. It says directly on the github page for agenda that there's no recommended layout, so trying to test the basic functionality by chuckin' it in my server.js seemed viable at first.

Nodemon starts up and crashes immediately with error but with no trace or information as to why. Startup:

> [nodemon] v1.2.1 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` 
>   [nodemon] watching: app/views/**/*.* gruntfile.js server.js
>   config/**/*.js app/**/*.js
>   [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I threw the agenda code in at the end I will say after some basic testing the app does NOT crash until these 2 lines are uncommented. I thought maybe it was something to do with my connection string, as that's the name of the database I'm already connected to for the main app. But again I ran out of information to draw from.

```
agenda.schedule('in 10 seconds', 'greet the world', {time: new Date()});
agenda.start();
```

---

```
    'use strict';
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var init = require('./config/init')(),
    config = require('./config/config'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    chalk = require('chalk'),
    Agenda = require('agenda');


/**
 * Main application entry file.
 * Please note that the order of loading is important.
 */

// Bootstrap db connection
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(chalk.red('Could not connect to MongoDB!'));
        console.log(chalk.red(err));
    }
});

// Init the express application
var app = require('./config/express')(db);

// Bootstrap passport config
require('./config/passport')();

// Start the app by listening on <port>
app.listen(config.port);

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;

// Logging initialization
console.log('Application started on port ' + config.port);


/////--------TESTING----------------
var agenda = new Agenda({
    db: {
        address: 'mongodb://localhost/consultations',
        collection: 'emailQueue'
        //options: {
        //    ssl: true
        //}
    }
});

agenda.define('greet the world', function(job, done) {
    console.log(job.attrs.data.time, 'hello world!');
    done();
});

agenda.schedule('in 10 seconds', 'greet the world', {time: new Date()});
agenda.start();

console.log('Wait 10 seconds...');
//////------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
agenda.on('ready', function() {
    agenda.define('greet the world', function(job, done) {
        console.log(job.attrs.data.time, 'hello world!');
        done();
    });

    agenda.schedule('in 10 seconds', 'greet the world', {
        time: new Date()
    });
    agenda.start();
});
```

also i had db like

```
var agenda = new Agenda({
    db: {
        address: 'localhost:27017/test' //default collection agendaJobs
    } 
});
```

*hope it helps*

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the great response. It... worked? As to say no more error... fixed one issue but revealed another as is often the case. After "successful" startup agenda does nothing. I kept the "console.log()" line after agenda.start(), it never logs that, like it's not going through the agenda.on block because maybe it never reaches "ready" state.

Comment: @JasonMacAnLighiche ok thats weird, vl look into it

Comment: I just moved the code to under my  var app = express(); line and added agenda-ui to see if I might be able to see if it was starting or not. When hitting the agenda-ui mount point, it's a blank page, not sure if related to the other issue. I am using ssl, and when using curl I do get the page with <title>Agenda UI</title>.

Comment: @JasonMacAnLighiche vl give it a try , but r u still not getting console.log() output , i vl create a git repo for my code , so that u can run it and see , give me 5 min

Comment: https://github.com/aishwat/trying_agenda download it , do `npm install`, change ur db config in `app.js` and do `nodemon app.js` by the time i vl look into ui stuff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95620/discussion-between-aishwat-singh-and-jason-mac-an-lighiche).

Comment: Ok, your example works! From that I realized my "mongo explorer" plugin for Webstorm wasn't refreshing my collections, I thought it wasn't entering anything into my database. So, reconnecting to the plugin and going back to where I was with your first response, I still don't get any working output from agenda in my project. BUT, it is creating a custom collection a database of my choice.